problem to transform from epsg:3116 to lat, long (epsg:4326) in dart-flutter
I was trying to convert from epsg:3116(gcm_magna) to epsg:4326(lat and long) using the lib but the outputs were inaccurate. Can some one explain me or correct me?

    var destProjection = Projection.get('EPSG:4326')!; // WGS84 (EPSG:4326)

    // Definir las coordenadas en EPSG:3116
    var point = Point(x: 846358.4308, y: 1639765.33);

    // Convertir las coordenadas de EPSG:3116 a EPSG:4326
    var transformedPoint = srcProjection.transform(destProjection, point);

    print('Latitud: ${transformedPoint.y}, Longitud: ${transformedPoint.x}');```

my inputs were: (x: 846358.4308, y: 1639765.33) and the expected outputs are Lat: 10.377944565887024, Long: -75.48036335262766. But I have Lat: 14.809695868343415, Long: -71.7825948906633


Update I made it. The problem I had was that, I was using a past version of the lib proj4dart, so I update it to the latest and change the code form:
flutter dependencies:
dependencies:
  proj4dart: ^2.1.0

code changed:
import 'package:proj4dart/proj4dart.dart';
void main() {
  var pointSrc = Point(x: 846358.4308, y: 1639765.33);

  var projSrc = Projection.add(
    'EPSG:3116',
    '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=4.59620041666667 +lon_0=-74.0775079166667 +k=1 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs',
  );

  var projDst = Projection.get('EPSG:4326')!;

  var pointForward = projSrc.transform(projDst, pointSrc);

  print(pointForward.toArray()); // Output: [-75.48036335262819, 10.37794456588702]
}

Big thanks to https://github.com/maRci002 who help me with the problem and is the owner of the lib proj4dart.
